# Visual Studio 2013 fatal error during insall

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying many many times to install Visual Studio 2013, but with no success.
I searched many websites like yours, forums and other things that have similar problem to mine and I applied all those intros, but no way to insall...last time I tried to install Proffesional version instead of Ultimate, same thing happened.
Here is my log file 
http://pastebin.ca/2645459

I tried to stop antivirus, clean temp folder, start install as Administrator and other stuff I found

Anyone can help please

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of errors like this is due to a corrupted installer. The first thing I'd try is downloading the installer again and rerunning it.